# Construct a meromorphic $1$-form on torus

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I am trying to solve the following question:

> Show that there a meromorphic $1$-form $\omega$ on a torus with
>
> - a double order pole at one point
> - a double order zero at another point
> - holomorphic elsewhere
> - has only real periods.
>
> Hint: Remove a parallelogram from the Euclidean plane and identify opposite edges by translation. Analyze the corresponding $1$-form and deduce how the parallelogram has to look like.

This hint does not make any sense to me. It is too vague for me... I cannot even imagine the space we obtained by the above procedure in hints...

Could anyone give me a more detailed hint or answer? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm struggling with Riemann surfaces too, so take this comment with a large grain of salt: I think the idea of the hint is just about telling you how to construct your torus (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_torus for a picture), so we can think of the torus as the image of the quotient map $q: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}/\Lambda$. Meromorphic 1-forms on $\mathbb{C}$ are of the form $f(z)\ dz$ for some meromorphism $f$ and locally the torus "looks like" $\mathbb{C}$, so I think the meromorphic 1-form on the torus is locally also of the form $f(z)\ dz$.

Comment: The periodicity I think relates to the lattice/parallelogram in the Wikipedia link, and I would guess that this enforces the condition that $f(z+\tau) = f(z)$ where $\tau$ is somehow related to the parallelogram. To repeat, I'm just learning this stuff too, so take it with a pinch of salt.

Comment: Source of this question?

Comment: @Y.Hu From one of my former homework... Not from some famous textbooks...

Comment: @AnCoileanach You are right. At first, "remove" misled me and I thought we should think a plane with a hole and glue the edges of the hole...

Comment: @AnCoileanach According to the answer, I think the peroid is related to the period of Weierstrass elliptic function: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure with the condition that $\omega$ has only real periods.

Despite that, there is a construction.

Let $\Lambda = \omega_1 \mathbb{Z} + \omega_2\mathbb{Z}$, $X = \mathbb{C}/\Lambda$. And write the associated Weierstrass elliptic function $\wp(z)$.
$$\wp(z) = \frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda-\{0\}}\frac{1}{(z+\lambda)^2}-\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$$
Then $\omega = (\wp(z) - \wp(\omega_1/2))dz$ is meromorphic with a double order pole at $0$, and double order zero at $\omega_1/2$.

Comment: The period of Weierstrass elliptic function is $1$ and $\omega_1/\omega_2$. If both of them are real, then $\omega_1=r\omega_2$ for some real number $r$. Then this can not be a lattice...

Comment: @AolongLi That's the point. I just cannot understand, how can something defined on a torus have only real periods? Since every torus with a complex structure is defined by a certain lattice.